# Using Hotswap agent with Jboss 5 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x, hotswap

Trying to configure  JBoss  5 to work with hotswapagent using eclipse. So far I have done the following:
Patched my jdk using DCEVM (installer-light-jdk7u71.2.jar)  with option - install DCEVM as aljvm. Jdk patched is v1.6_45 (which Jboss uses).
Downloaded the lastet version of hotswap-agent.jar and added vm arg to my server configuration: XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:C:\tools\hotswap-agent.jar

However when I start the server I get the follwing error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hotswap/agent/HotswapAgent : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
```

am I using the wrong version of hotswap  to run with jdk v1.6? any help please

Comment: Looks like a `JRE` mismatch.  Version `51.0` is for `J2SE 7`.  Check your Java settings (path & classpath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, **HotswapAgent** works with [JDK 7 and above](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent#install).

Or

If you want to use JDK v1.6_45, try to *patch* the JDK using the binaries available [here](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/binaries/).

Also noticed that there is a **hyphen** (`-`) missing in your `XXaltjvm=dcevm` configuration.  It should be `-XXaltjvm=dcevm`

Comment: I have been using Jrebel (trial) but would soon need to revert back to DCEM and see if I can get it working. Tnx